# How to convert List<model> to string?

Tags: c#, dynamicobject, tree-structure

I have a list of data and want to convert it into string format like headers and values separated. How can I achieve this in c#?

[image]
[image]

Expected Result:

```
dynamic data = {
  "values": [
    [
      5658830,
      "Support And Training Services Llc",
      "PAM",
      "FINNESAND"
    ],
    [
      5658831,
      "Training Services Llc",
      "Bob",
      "MCCART"
    ]
  ],
  "headers": [
    "ID",
    "ENT_COMPANY1",
    "FirstName",
    "LastName"
  ]
}
```

How to convert in List into above format?

Comment: I don't see a tree, here but alas. What have you tried?

Comment: Why this is stored in this way at all? Why you don't serialize a type to json which you can deserialize and then easily modify? `dynamic data` should be a class `Data` which contains a property `Headers` and a `List<Value> Values`. Then you can easily remove the value with `ID=5658830` from the list and serialize it back to json.

Comment: I want values and headers to be separate.  In JSON data I will get [{"ID":5658830,"ENT_COMPANY1": "Training Services Llc"}] don't want this

Comment: Then do what @TimSchmelter said.

Comment: ok now I have List<Classdata> with the expected result. Now how to convert  List<Classdata> into values and headers format string? @TimSchmelter

Comment: Show the class (update the question) especially how the values property looks like you should have now in that class.

Comment: Question updated. Please check

Comment: Your expected result is not a string, yet your question (and title) is saying you want a string. If you can't hardcode your headers, then use reflection to get the properties of your type. Loop through the properties, then loop through the values, and build your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick snippet to answer your question, in my own code.  You'll still have to propogate the list of objects with whatever it is you have.  Just change "object" to the name of your model.

```
        List<string> listOfStrings = new List<string>();
        List<object> listOfMyModels = new List<object>();
        
        //fill your list of objects here with whatever it is you're converting to a string

        foreach(object myObject in listOfMyModels)
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);
            listOfStrings.Add(json);
        }
```

Now you have a list of strings that represent your objects and when needed, you can use the deserialize method to read it.